# Почему не работают скрипты в spring-boot приложении

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot

Начинаю разбираться с javascrypt, пытался подключить jquery, написал скрипт, скрипт в нетворке вроде подключается, но скрипт в документе почему-то не работает.
pom.xml

```
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/3.4.1/jquery.min.js}"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Andrew Tate</h1>
    <button id="myButton" class="btn btn-primary">Click me</button>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("myButton").on("click", function (e) {
            alert("You have clicked me");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Структура проекта:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для кнопки в JS не хватает `#`.

Должно получится так:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myButton").on("click", function (e) {
            alert("You have clicked me");
        });
});
```

Для выбора элемента по `id` используется - `#`, для класса - `.`, для тега - название (например `button`, `h1`).